Gitlab with SSL
I am trying to set up a simple gitlab with SSL.
I have the following set up in a docker-compose.yaml file:
version: '3.6'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:16.5.1-ee.0'
    restart: always
    hostname:  'gitlab.env-pri.com'
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.env-pri.com:8443'
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        nginx['enable'] = true
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.env-pri.com.crt"
        nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.env-pri.com.key"
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '2224:22'
      - '8443:443'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - '/home/user1/gitlab/certs:/etc/gitlab/ssl:ro'
    shm_size: '256m'
    networks:
      - gitlab
networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network

The certs were created(the .crt file is the concatenation of the server.crt, intermediate and the root crt) and then verified by:
openssl verify -CAfile root.crt -untrusted intermediate.crt gitlab.env-pri.com.crt
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in gitlab.env-pri.com.key | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in gitlab.env-pri.com.crt | openssl md5

After running the yaml, I check using
curl -kv gitlab.env-pri.com:8443
It fails.
I turn of the firewall and ran it again:
curl -kv https://gitlab.env-pri.com:8443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://gitlab.env-pri.com:8443/
*   Trying *.*.*.*...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gitlab.env-pri.com (*.*.*.*) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.env-pri.com:8443
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.env-pri.com:8443

OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.env-pri.com:8443

curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.env-pri.com:8443

Has anyone come across this or does anyone know a fix?

I think ssh connections to gitlab start with git@.... and not https:....

That is the endpoint of the UI.

What do the nginx logs say? If you (can and do) run ss -tln or possibly netstat -tln in the container does it show nginx listening on 443? This symptom (SYSCALL error on ClientHello) occurs with some virtual networking where the port is configured but not actually being listened to.

Wouldn't it open the port 8443 on the host machine.

netstat -tln | grep 8443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
